# Travis CI won't build though I push my app to GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, travis-ci

I want Travis CI to build my app for test when I push my app to GitHub.

I think there is cooperation between Travis CI and GitHub.

But it didn't work.

docker-compose.yml here.

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  db-data:

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/product-register'
    environment:
      - 'DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres'
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - 'db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust'
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres'
```

.travis.yml here.

```
sudo: required

services: docker

before_install:
  - docker login -u polymetisoutis -p 5fb47200-dd19-4772-a9ad-c98913ef1cb9
  - docker-compose up --build -d

script:
  - docker-compose exec --env 'RAILS_ENV=test' web rails db:create
  - docker-compose exec --env 'RAILS_ENV=test' web rails db:migrate
  - docker-compose exec --env 'RAILS_ENV=test' web rails test
```

Then repository I pushed to GitHub here.⇒https://github.com/PolymetisOutis/product-register

After the next command executed,
`git push origin master`

I think Travis CI should build the app on the travis-ci.com page for test.

But Travis CI didn't work.

Why?

Is there anyone who have an idea and clue about this?

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/

Comment: Thank you so much!! Also thanks for your editing.
I think I am following the correct procedure like the tutorial.
But this happened!!

Comment: As you can see my GitHub repository,it's not private project. So I think I can use Travis CI service for free plan. Why Travis CI won't build???

Answer (score 0):

Your Travis CI Build Request Page [1] always gives the idea of why the build wasn't triggered actually. I can see that at a time that you have triggered some requests your account wasn't confirmed and your build requests were rejected, however, now seems like you are able to trigger builds.

[1] https://app.travis-ci.com/github/PolymetisOutis/product-register/requests

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I contacted support engineers, and It's settled.
I had to do the free plan procedure to build my app.
That's why it didn't work.

Comment: Happy to hear that. The page I have attached has the reject reason displayed when you visit so I think you can accept this as an answer. Thanks